# Can a predeclared type implement an interface in Go?

Tags: go

Let's say that I have an interface, `Key`, which has a method `Hash() int`, that I would like to use in a collection struct in Go.  I would like to be able to do things in my collection such as `(c *Collection) Set(key Key, value Value)`.  I would like my collection to be able to be keyed on predeclared types, such as `type IntKey int`, so that I can take advantage of some limited implicit typing while implementing `(k IntKey) Hash() int`.  Is this possible, or to I need to declare `IntKey` as a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any (non built-in) type can satisfy an interface, thus:

```
type IntKey int

func (k IntKey) Hash() int { ... }
```

and ...

```
type Collection struct {
    // fields
}

func (c Collection) Hash() int { ... }
```

Both satisfy your `Key` interface. Further reading: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types

Comment: Thank you; this confirms what I had expected... now on to my next problem.

Comment: I found this this post very useful: http://research.swtch.com/interfaces